# Unable to click image when put it in a div with custom style

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have three styles, the first two is for div, the last one is for the image. The image can be clicked without the div. But I need the div effect, how could I solve this issue. Now the image doesn't reponse to onClick.

```js
const onclick=(e)=>{
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('clicked')
}
```

```css
.start-screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 2.3%;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 91vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    top,
    #0a0a0a 0,
    rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.58) 58%
  );
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#start {
  transition-duration: 2s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.schema{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 35%;
    display: block;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="start-screen" id="start">
  <img class="transport" src='imgs/transportDiagram.png'  alt='fail to load services' onClick="onclick">
</div>
```

Comment: You need to reset `pointer-events` for the image. (Not sure if the `.schema` rule was supposed to do that, but your image does not have this class, so it would not apply …)

Comment: Yes indeed; `pointer-events: none` **prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element**. Source: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: Yes, you are all right. Actually the code I show can work. I just click another image. Sorry for my mistake. I need to use the right class

Answer (score 0):

You should add the click event in the div.

```
<div className="start-screen" id="start" onClick={onclick}>
        <img className="transport" src='imgs/transportDiagram.png'  alt='fail to load services'  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake that didn't use the right class name. Change className='transport' to 'schema' would work.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this will work

```
    <div className="start-screen" id="start">
        <img className="transport" src='imgs/transportDiagram.png'  alt='fail to load services' onClick={() => onclick()} />
    </div>
```

Comment: no. The image can be click if without div. so it is not the problem of onclick